# How to pass multiple data in state?

Tags: reactjs

**I need the output like this**

```
{
        id: 1,
        image: "/assets/images/3d-rendering.png",
        name: "Screen",
        mrp: 950.8,
        sale_price: 950,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        image: "/assets/images/charger.png",
        name: "Screen2",
        mrp: 950.1,
        sale_price: 951,
      },
```

I declare the addnow in array.

```
const [addnow, setAddnow] = useState([]);
```

when i click **Add Now** button the hole data send to the state value.

```
 {repairservicedata.map((data, index) => (
                      <div className={Styles.repaircard} key={index}>
                        <div className={Styles.repaircardins}>
                          <img src={data.image} alt="" />
                          <div>
                            <h6>{data.name}</h6>
                            <span className={Styles.pricestrkoutcard}>
                              {data.mrp}
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className={Styles.priceblock}>
                          <h5 className={Styles.price}> {data.sale_price}</h5>
                          <Button
                            className={Styles.addnwbtn}
                            onClick={() => handleaddnowFunc(data)}
                          >
                            Add Now
                          </Button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    ))}
```

This is the function i added. but it's not getting the old data and add the new data. it shows **addnow is not iterable**

```
const handleaddnowFunc = (data) => {
    if (addnow.length === 0) {
      setAddnow(data);
    } else {
      setAddnow([...addnow, { data }]);
    }
  };
```

I need to pass multiple json data in single state value.

Comment: how did you define `addnow`

Comment: const [addnow, setAddnow] = useState([]); This how i define the addnow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the data this way:

```js
const handleaddnowFunc = data => {
   setAddNow(prevState => ([...prevState, data]));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to set data like this

```
setAddnow([...addnow.map(d => ({...d})), { ...data }]);
```

Comment: addnow.map is not a function or its return value is not iterable showing this error

Comment: what is the type of addNow?? Isn't it an array?

Comment: const [addnow, setAddnow] = useState([]); it's in array only

Comment: Initially you need to set data like setAddnow([data]); when addNow.length === 0

Answer (score 0):

What type of addnow?

there are two reasons for this

1. it is a strict type state array that's why it is not iterable;
   therefore, you must clone this array and then iterable this addnow array.
2. you have declared another type like {}.

got it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).